# Disable panning when dragging a pushpin

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, bing-maps, pushpin, panning

I'm trying to prevent the WPF Bing Maps control from panning when the user is dragging a pushpin. What I do is that when the user selecting the pushpin with the MouseLeftButtonDown I'm, taking over the events from the map ViewChangeStart, ViewChangeOnFrame and set the e.Handled property to true.

What I was expecting is that if I set the property to true the events are canceled and panning is disabled. However the map is still panning.

Another approach what I tried is setting the property SupportedManipulations to None. Both options don't have the expected results.

Below is the code that I'm using for my DraggablePushpin

```
 public class DraggablePushpin : Pushpin
    {
        private bool isDragging = false;

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var parentLayer = this.Parent as MapLayer;
            if (parentLayer != null)
            {
                Map parentMap = parentLayer.Tag as Map;
                if (parentMap != null)
                {
                    parentMap.ViewChangeStart += parentMap_ViewChangeStart;
                    parentMap.MouseLeftButtonUp += parentMap_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                    parentMap.MouseMove += parentMap_MouseMove;

                    parentMap.SupportedManipulations = System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.Manipulations2D.None;
                }
            }

            this.isDragging = true;

            base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        }

        void parentMap_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var map = sender as Map;
            // Check if the user is currently dragging the Pushpin
            if (this.isDragging)
            {
                // If so, the Move the Pushpin to where the Mouse is.
                var mouseMapPosition = e.GetPosition(map);
                var mouseGeocode = map.ViewportPointToLocation(mouseMapPosition);
                this.Location = mouseGeocode;
            }
        }

        void parentMap_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Map).SupportedManipulations = System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.Manipulations2D.All;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var parentLayer = this.Parent as MapLayer;
            if (parentLayer != null)
            {
                Map parentMap = parentLayer.Tag as Map;
                if (parentMap != null)
                {
                    parentMap.SupportedManipulations = System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.Manipulations2D.All;
                }
            }
        }

        void parentMap_ViewChangeStart(object sender, MapEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.isDragging)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should perhaps add the `parentMap_MouseMove` handler to `parentMap.PreviewMouseMove` instead of `parentMap.MouseMove` and set `e.Handled = true;` to suppress handling of the mouse move event in the Map control.

Comment: That's actually stopping the panning, but also the ability to drag the pushpin.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, as the Pushpin is a child of the map. Then you should add a handler to `PushPin.PreviewMouseMove` (or override `OnPreviewMouseMove`), i guess. Do the dragging there and then stop event propagation by setting `e.Handled`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens for your suggestions. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. But still i think canceling MouseMove event propagation is the right way to go. What about putting an empty MapLayer on top of the map and intercept MouseMove event there. When dragging mode is active, cancel event propagation and move the PushPin.